# D7 Views 3: Filter by relationship based on nid and uid

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type 'contest' that users submit guesses on. The guesses are entities that have `uid` and `nid` properties (and of course their own primary key, `gid`) to record the user and the contest to which they belong.

How can I display only contests on which a given user has submitted guesses?
A similar problem might be how to return only nodes of a certain type that a given user has commented on.

By using this within `hook_views_data` and setting the query to distinct (which I'd also prefer not to have to do) within the Views UI, I was able to confine the results to nodes that have guesses whose `nid` property match - but I can't figure out how to confine the results to nodes with guess entities whose `nid` AND `uid` properties match:

```
$data['node']['nid'] = array(
    'relationship' => array(
        'handler'        => 'views_handler_relationship',
        'base'           => 'entity_guess',
        'base field'     => 'nid',
        'title'          => t('Has guesses'),
        'label'          => t('contests with guesses'),
    ),
);
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is this doable? I know it must be. I just can't find any great documentation on the Views API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up achieving the result that I wanted with hook_views_query_alter:

```
function site_views_query_alter (& $view, & $query)
{
  if ('block_3' == $view->current_display) {
    $account        = SiteUser::loadByID(arg(1), TRUE);
    $query->where[] = array(
      'conditions' => array(
        array(
          'field'    => 'node.nid',
          // Return just the IDs
          'value'    => SiteContest::getContestsPlayedBy($account, TRUE),
          'operator' => 'in',
        ),
      ),
      'args'       => array(),
      'type'       => 'AND',
    );
  }
}
```